# Selenium Python - how to get a current value of a text field if there is no attribute that holds such value?

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom

So my problem is as follows, the input tag in HTML has no attribute that would reflect the current text in this input field (think of "value" attribute in google search that holds the value you enter) so the question is - what are my options to get this text in order to assert it?

I've already tried input.text and input.get_attribute() - no luck.

Example from the-internet.herokuapp.com:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3kPS.jpg)

Code snippet:

```
def sample_test():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.maximize_window()
    base_url = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login"
    driver.get(base_url)
    input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']")
    print(input.text) # I expect this to print nothing as at this point the field is empty
    input.send_keys("asdasd")
    print(input.text) # Here I was hoping it will print "asdasd" but was also empty
```

Comment: Have you tried `input.get_attribute("value")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element `value` attribute value as following:

```
input_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']")get_attribute("value")
```

It's common that input elements containing their text values as value attribute, not as a "text"

Comment: Have you seen the img I attached? There is no 'value' attribute in HTML- if there was, I wouldn't be asking this question and just used get_attribute method. My question is how to get the value 'asdasd' WHEN it's not held in any attribute in HTML.

Comment: Did you TRY getting that attribute?

Comment: Please accept my apologies - I did try that now and yes - the value was printed to the console! Would you mind sharing how is that possible and how does this work under the hood?

Comment: Well, I'm not a front end developer, just an automation developer, so I would say it's some JavaScript issue, I don't know. You are welcome to ask this question separately since this is definitely a new question. It would be interesting to know the answer!

Comment: I have asked this question myself, several answers were answered there, but the correct one is what I answered myself, this is what our our FE developer described me. You can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758297/why-input-elements-value-attributes-are-sometimes-not-presented-in-the-html