# Partial text gets retrieved from getTextFromXpath function where we are passing a xpath to the function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, relative-locators

I have created a function as written below, under the action utility under the framework:

```
public String getTextByXpath(WebElement xpath) throws Exception {
        waitForXPath("wait for element", xpath);
        Assert.assertNotNull(xpath);
        LOG().info("Element to get text is Present");
        String value = xpath.getAttribute("value");
        LOG().info("Actual Text:" + value);
        return value;
    }
```

Where I'm passing a web element's(input field) path to get the text.

For e.g

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='gwt-uid-5643']") 
WebElement input_UserName;
```

this is an input field where the value contains some text concatenated with the current date & time but it's not dynamic.

Given that the element is present & visible, using this function gets me a partial value from i.e. only the text part from the input field, not the date/time which was appended to the text.

I have tried different methods  but still had no success.

Comment: Does the current date & time get appended by some javascript code? You mention it's not dynamic, but unless someone is entering it manually, the `xpath.getAttribute("value")` will not contain it.

Comment: You can also check [Why input elements "value" attributes are sometimes not presented in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67758297/2453382)

Comment: Nope, that was actually a record that was added via import script, & this script was intended to verify that the report data is successfully uploaded.

Comment: Update the question with the text based html of the element.